# I need a non repeated random string

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to make a random image or text
And it’s take a String okay,
But however I try to make a random list with string, it’s always return a similar result (images or text) and i want all The images to be different!!?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh78S.jpg

Comment: please clarify what You want: a) generate random string, b) randomize list (array) of strings ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`shuffle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/shuffle.html) method to get a random sorting for your list, then you can just iterate on it.

```
shuffle(myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want random values (String, image, etc) not repeateable maybe you should try with Set, an iterable that doesn't allow to have 2 equal objects

I don't know how you randomize or insert the values but just pass them to the set and it will ignore all duplicates

```
Set<String> mySet = Set.from(//pass your list here);
```

Now it will have no duplicates Strings, or you can just convert the list to set and go back

```
myList.toSet().toList(); //myList is the List you already have
```